# Google Visualization drow columns in descending order

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have this chart:
[image]

Columns are in ascending order (0,1,2...).

How can I change order like 6,5,4...?

Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using option...

```
hAxis: {
  direction: -1
}
```

> The direction in which the values along the horizontal axis grow. Specify -1 to reverse the order of the values.